# Pandas dataframe replaces strings with NaN using pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, nan

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of strings, i.e 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', ..., null.

When I try to concatenate this data frame with another, all of the strings get replaced with 'NaN'.

See my code below:

```
descriptions = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/master/data/v02/eclipse/short_desc.json')
descriptions = descriptions.reset_index(drop=1)
descriptions['desc'] = descriptions.short_desc.apply(operator.itemgetter(0)).apply(operator.itemgetter('what'))
f1=pd.DataFrame(descriptions['desc'])

bugPrior = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/master/data/v02/eclipse/priority.json')
bugPrior = bugPrior.reset_index(drop=1)
bugPrior['priority'] = bugPrior.priority.apply(operator.itemgetter(0)).apply(operator.itemgetter('what'))
f2=pd.DataFrame(bugPrior['priority'])

df = pd.concat([f1,f2])
print(df.head())
```

The output is as follows:

```
              desc                                     priority
0    Usability issue with external editors (1GE6IRL)      NaN
1             API - VCM event notification (1G8G6RR)      NaN
2  Would like a way to take a write lock on a tea...      NaN
3  getter/setter code generation drops "F" in ".....      NaN
4  Create Help Index Fails with seemingly incorre...      NaN
```

Any ideas as to how I might stop this from happening?

Ultimately, my goal is to have everything in a single data frame so that I might removes all rows with "null" values. It would also help later on in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to concatenate those columns horizontally, you'll need to pass `axis=1` to `pd.concat`, because by default, concatenation is vertical.

```
df = pd.concat([f1,f2], axis=1)
```

---

To drop those `NaN` rows, you should be able to use `df.dropna`. Call `df.reset_index` after.

```
df = pd.concat([f1, f2], 1)
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df.head(10))
                                                desc priority
0  Create Help Index Fails with seemingly incorre...       P3
1  Internal compiler error when compiling switch ...       P3
2  Default text sizes in org.eclipse.jface.resour...       P3
3  [Presentations] [ViewMgmt] Holding mouse down ...       P3
4  Parsing of function declarations in stdio.h is...       P2
5  CCE in RenameResourceAction while renaming ele...       P3
6  Option to prevent cursor from moving off end o...       P3
7        Tasks section in the user doc is very stale       P3
8  Importing existing project with different case...       P3
9  Workspace in use --> choose new workspace but ...       P3
```

Printing out `df.priority.unique()`, we see there are 5 unique priorities:

```
print(df.priority.unique())
array(['P3', 'P2', 'P4', 'P1', 'P5'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this dataset is driving m nuts already, and this is just the data import!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best there is not create DataFrames from columns:

```
descriptions = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/master/data/v02/eclipse/short_desc.json')
descriptions = descriptions.reset_index(drop=1)

#get Series to f1
f1 = descriptions.short_desc.apply(operator.itemgetter(0)).apply(operator.itemgetter('what'))
print (f1.head())

bugPrior = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/master/data/v02/eclipse/priority.json')
bugPrior = bugPrior.reset_index(drop=1)

#get Series to f2
f2 = bugPrior.priority.apply(operator.itemgetter(0)).apply(operator.itemgetter('what'))
print (f2.head())
```

Then use same solution as [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943483/2901002) answer:

```
df = pd.concat([f1,f2], axis=1).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df.head())
                                          short_desc priority
0  Create Help Index Fails with seemingly incorre...       P3
1  Internal compiler error when compiling switch ...       P3
2  Default text sizes in org.eclipse.jface.resour...       P3
3  [Presentations] [ViewMgmt] Holding mouse down ...       P3
4  Parsing of function declarations in stdio.h is...       P2
```

Comment: This is exactly my answer. :)

Comment: It's okay. You didn't have to make that edit, but thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your answer. I think I might apply your recommendation and just create columns.

Comment: @jezrael There are no problems. I actually upvoted your answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks ;)